# Generate time dimension in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, data-warehouse

Im trying to make a mysql table with the following fields:
Year,month,day,hour,minute

From 10 years ago to 10 years ahead.

I have this that creates it for days, but it doesnt include hours and minutes

```
SET @d0 = "2012-01-01";
SET @d1 = "2012-12-31";

SET @date = date_sub(@d0, interval 1 day);

# set up the time dimension table
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS time_dimension;
CREATE TABLE `time_dimension` (
`date` date DEFAULT NULL,
`id` int NOT NULL,
`y` smallint DEFAULT NULL,
`m` smallint DEFAULT NULL,
`d` smallint DEFAULT NULL,
`yw` smallint DEFAULT NULL,
`w` smallint DEFAULT NULL,
`q` smallint DEFAULT NULL,
`wd` smallint DEFAULT NULL,
`m_name`  char(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`wd_name` char(10) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

# populate the table with dates
INSERT INTO time_dimension
SELECT @date := date_add(@date, interval 1 day) as date,
# integer ID that allows immediate understanding
date_format(@date, "%Y%m%d") as id,
year(@date) as y,
month(@date) as m,
day(@date) as d,
date_format(@date, "%x") as yw,
week(@date, 3) as w,
quarter(@date) as q,
weekday(@date)+1 as wd,
monthname(@date) as m_name,
dayname(@date) as wd_name
FROM T
WHERE date_add(@date, interval 1 day) <= @d1
ORDER BY date
;
```

how can i modify it so it also do hours and minutes?
Thanks!

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't want to use a timestamp for this?  I think managing so many disparate time components could get messy at some point.

Comment: But whhhyyyyy? Oh, the humanity :-(

Comment: Please please tell us why you want to do this?  What's the purpose for a table that stores a record of time for every minute within a 20 year period?

Comment: i want to store historical data of 17k stock market simbols, i think that it will not only prevent inconsistencies when comunicating with the data provider (cause the time dimension table would have an index preventing duplicates) , but also it would be faster to retrieve series, cause i will not have to group by on the fly based on a timestamp, it would go throw the index on the timedimension

Comment: I do not understand why you want to do this, however, you could check out the MySQL documentation on date_add() function and check if there are other functions in MySQL that retrieve other parts of a datetime value (yes, there are). Based on these you can update your query.

Comment: @gabrielmellace unique index on the time dimension only would not prevent duplicate values, you need a multi-column unique index on the time dimension and the market symbols. You could just index the timestamp column.

Comment: @Shadow timestamp differs on seconds, i only go up to minutes, yes i could round it on the app, but again, when im performing a select, im not going throw an index. if i have the dimensions, then i could first select the timeframe i want from it, get the ids and then left join with the table that have the quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you opt for a Time Dimension, it is recommended that you separate Date and Time dimensions, combining both will result in >10m records for your dimension while separating Date and Time dimensions will give you 7300 row for the Date Dimension and 1440 row for the Time Dimension (hour/minute) you will then need a foregin key to the Time Dimension in your fact table the same way you are designing it with the Date Dimension.

Comment: and that its a really good idea! thanks! do you know how can i generate these dimensions?

Comment: @gabrielmellace it seems like the script in this Q works for mysql http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413175/time-dimension-fill-problem

Comment: do you know how can i modify it to only do minutes and not seconds?

Comment: the script in the Question does not include seconds, just like what you are looking for, I guess you were looking at the second answer's script? just create the table sc_time first (or rename it) then create the procedure and run it (replace currentdate with datetime as in the accepted answer) unfortunately I don't have mySql to test

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I am using

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS time_dimension;
CREATE TABLE time_dimension (
        id                      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,  -- year*10000+month*100+day
        db_date                 DATE NOT NULL,
        year                    INTEGER NOT NULL,
        month                   INTEGER NOT NULL, -- 1 to 12
        day                     INTEGER NOT NULL, -- 1 to 31
        quarter                 INTEGER NOT NULL, -- 1 to 4
        week                    INTEGER NOT NULL, -- 1 to 52/53
        day_name                VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL, -- 'Monday', 'Tuesday'...
        month_name              VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL, -- 'January', 'February'...
        holiday_flag            CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'f' CHECK (holiday_flag in ('t', 'f')),
        weekend_flag            CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'f' CHECK (weekday_flag in ('t', 'f')),
        UNIQUE td_ymd_idx (year,month,day),
        UNIQUE td_dbdate_idx (db_date)

) Engine=MyISAM;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS fill_date_dimension;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE fill_date_dimension(IN startdate DATE,IN stopdate DATE)
BEGIN
    DECLARE currentdate DATE;
    SET currentdate = startdate;
    WHILE currentdate <= stopdate DO
        INSERT INTO time_dimension VALUES (
            YEAR(currentdate)*10000+MONTH(currentdate)*100 + DAY(currentdate),
            currentdate,
            YEAR(currentdate),
            MONTH(currentdate),
            DAY(currentdate),
            QUARTER(currentdate),
            WEEKOFYEAR(currentdate),
            DATE_FORMAT(currentdate,'%W'),
            DATE_FORMAT(currentdate,'%M'),
            'f',
            CASE DAYOFWEEK(currentdate) WHEN 1 THEN 't' WHEN 7 then 't' ELSE 'f' END
            );
        SET currentdate = ADDDATE(currentdate,INTERVAL 1 DAY);
    END WHILE;
END
//
DELIMITER ;

TRUNCATE TABLE time_dimension;
CALL fill_date_dimension('1800-01-01','2050-01-01');
OPTIMIZE TABLE time_dimension;
```